# Take a working http get request (3rd party api) and use fetch instead, but signature does not match

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I am trying to take a working http get request and use fetch instead but I get an error returned that signature does not match from 3rd party api when using fetch.

Original:

```
var secret = 'HIDDEN'
var id = 'HIDDEN'
const params = 'action=results&zip=' + zip + '&miles=' + mile
var timestamp = moment.utc().format("ddd, D MMM YYYY HH:mm:00 [GMT]");
var signature = timestamp + secret + params + id
var sha = CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create();
sha.update(signature);
var encrypt = sha.finalize();
return http.get({
    host: 'www.vtinfo.com',
    path: '/PF/product_finder-service.asp?' + params,
    headers: {
        'vipCustID': id,
        'vipTimestamp': timestamp,
        'vipSignature': encrypt
    }
})
```

Attempt using fetch:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
var secret = 'HIDDEN'
var id = 'HIDDEN'
const params = 'action=results&zip=' + zip + '&miles=' + mile
var timestamp = moment.utc().format("ddd, D MMM YYYY HH:mm:00 [GMT]");
var signature = timestamp + secret + params + id
var sha = CryptoJS.algo.SHA256.create();
sha.update(signature);
var encrypt = sha.finalize();
return fetch('https://www.vtinfo.com/PF/product_finder-service.asp?' + params, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'vipCustID': id,
        'vipTimestamp': timestamp,
        'vipSignature': encrypt
    }
})
```

I am not too familiar with using fetch but its how I will be able to get correct output on the platform I am using.

Comment: I solved my issue by using request-promise npm instead of fetch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using request-promise npm instead of fetch

Answer (score 0):

Fetch is a browser API.
If you want to use it in Node try this:
[node-fetch npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

Comment: I am using node-fetch

Answer (score 0):

node.js does not have built-in `fetch` lib, if you want to use it you can use [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)

or you can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) also, this one is quite popular.

Comment: I am using node-fetch